# "Failed to do" vs "failed doing"

Tags: grammaticality

I work in software development, and today I got into a discussion with a coworker about how to write an error message.

Which would be better?

> Failed to store the value in the database.

Or

> Failed storing the value in the database.

Are both correct?

Answer (score 1):

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fail) says

> If you ***fail to do*** something that you were trying to do, you are unable to do it or do not succeed in doing it.
>
> - The Workers' Party ***failed to win*** a single governorship.

And [Gymglish](https://www.gymglish.com/en/gymglish/english-translation/fail#:%7E:text=Note%20the%20most%20common%20constructions,I%20failed%20my%20exams%20miserably.) explains:

> Note the most common constructions of the verb "to fail":
>
> - "to fail + object (I failed my math test)";
> - ***"to fail + to + infinitive verb*** (He *failed to warn* me about the hurricane)";
> - '***to fail + in/at + ING verb*** (I *failed in negotiating* the contract).

I would personally prefer ***failed to store*** to *failed in storing*.

Answer (score 1):

Writing error messages is a thing. You must be hyper aware of ["elephant in my pajamas"](https://www.shmoop.com/quotes/i-shot-an-elephant-in-my-pajamas.html) type things.

- One morning I shot an elephant in my pajamas. How he got in my pajamas, I don't know. *Captain Spaulding* played by Groucho Marx, in the movie "Animal Crackers."

When you are writing a computer error message, you do not necessarily have the context to know it is quite unlikely for the elephant to be wearing **MY** pajamas. (Instead of, for example, his own.) Indeed, because you are checking for any conceivable error condition, you might get crowded into such superficially absurd situations.

When you are writing error messages, first get the intended meaning correct. Then get the grammar correct. Error messages must communicate what you intend. Being grammatically correct is a "nice to have" but can be sacrificed if necessary. For example, error messages do not have to be complete sentences. Though it is very good if they are.

Your error messages leave the subject implied. Maybe this is acceptable, maybe not. What did the failing? Possibly there is context that supplies this, maybe in the error reporting system.

Your two messages communicate different things.

- Failed to store the value in the database.

This says that the failure occurred in such a way that the value did not get stored. It *seems* to imply that nothing got changed in the database.

- Failed storing the value in the database.

This says a failure occurred, but whether the value is in the database or not is not clear. It says the failure occurred "storing." This seems to indicate mid-process someplace, a failure occurred.

Once we are sensitized to this, we look back at the first message and start to think about it.  If the process of storing the value failed, what is in the database? Is the elephant in the pajamas or not?

So there are a number of ways you could rewrite this message, depending on the state of the database afterwards. Here are just two that you might choose between on the basis of what is left in the database after the failure.

- Store-to-database operation failed. Value in database unchanged.
- Store-to-database operation failed. Value in database undefined.